# How to declare STL list as global variable in Windows Forms Application project?

Tags: c++

I try to declare STL "list" as global in windows forms application, and place it in public declaration, because I need to use this "list" object as global in each callback function. so I try to declare `list <string> nodeList;` in public, but compiler error shows "error C4378:cannot define 'nodeList' as member of Form1, mixed types are not supported, could anyone help me give any suggestion?

Many Thanks

```
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;
using namespace System::IO;
using namespace std;
using namespace System::Collections::Generic;

using std::string;
using std::list;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;


public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{

public:

    /* I hope declare STL list, object is nodeList */
    /* I wish nodeList as global variable */
    /* nodeList must be used in button call back function (button_add_Click) */
    /* Is anything wrong declare here ? */
    list <string> nodeList;

    Form1(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    void MarshalString (String ^ s, string& os) {
        using namespace Runtime::InteropServices;
        const char* chars = 
        (const char*)(Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(s)).ToPointer();
        os = chars;
        Marshal::FreeHGlobal(IntPtr((void*)chars));
    }


protected:

    ~Form1()
    {
        if (components)
        {
            delete components;
        }
    }


protected: 


private:
    System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;



private: System::Void button_add_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

        int index;
        String^ curItem;
        String^ delay;
        String^ temp;
        string addItem;

        curItem = listBox_action_item -> SelectedItem -> ToString();
        delay = textBox_delay->Text;
        listBox_script_show->Items->Add(curItem + " 延遲" + delay + "秒");

            //temp = "Landscape " + delay;
            //MarshalString(temp,addItem);
            nodeList.push_back("abc");
            nodeList.push_back("def");
            nodeList.push_back("ghi");


     }
```

Comment: Have you written #include <list>

Comment: If you want it to be a global variable, why is it a member variable?

Comment: In order to declare a global object (which is usually a bad idea) in a header file, you will need `extern` and a second line defining the object in exactly one translation unit (source file).

Comment: This isn't C++. I think it may be C++/CLI.